# Reusing model property as a source of SelectList items causes incorrect option selected in one the select controlls

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

In my model I have declared property for AvailableOptions along with some 3 other properties for 3 different options with same value range:

```
public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> AvailableOptions{ get; set; }
public SomeCustomEnum? OptionNumberOne{ get; set; }
public SomeCustomEnum? OptionNumberTwo{ get; set; }
public SomeCustomEnum? OptionNumberThree{ get; set; }
```

I'm populating it only in one place of application, model builder, with collection of SelectListItems based on some enum value.

Than, I'm using it in 3 different places in the view for 3 different controls:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.OptionNumberOne, Model.AvailableOptions, "Choose...")
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.OptionNumberTwo, Model.AvailableOptions, "Choose...")
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.OptionNumberThree, Model.AvailableOptions, "Choose...")
```

When I have set values for the model properties in model builder to

```
OptionNumberOne = null;
OptionNumberTwo = SomeCustomEnum.Value1;
OptionNumberThree = null;
```

I'm getting 3 select dropdown controls with preselected values, but instead of expected default selected values

```
"Choose..."
"Value1"
"Choose..."
```

I got

```
"Choose..."
"Value1"
"Value1"
```

What am I missing here? if I add different values to those options (not null) they will render with correct selected value. Also, seems like adding another AvailableOptions property (AvailableOptions2) and binding it to the 3rd drop down fixes that case, but I don't want to do it that way. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You may try

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.OptionNumberOne, new SelectList(Model.AvailableOptions,"Value",
   "Text"), "Choose...")
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.OptionNumberTwo,new SelectList(Model.AvailableOptions,"Value",
   "Text"), "Choose...")
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.OptionNumberThree,new SelectList(Model.AvailableOptions,"Value",
   "Text"), "Choose...")
```

Comment: With that I end up with 3 times "Choose...", values don't get selected

Comment: Edited answer. Works fine on my trial.

Answer (score 0):

Use ModelState.Clear() statement before returning to view.